# sqlalchemy FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to implement FULL OUTER JOIN in sqlalchemy  on orm level.

Here my code:

```
q1 = (db.session.query(
        tb1.user_id.label('u_id'),
        func.count(tb1.id).label('tb1_c')
    )
    .group_by(tb1.user_id)
)
q2 = (db.session.query(
        tb2.user_id.label('u_id'),
        func.count(tb2.id).label('tb2_c')
    )
    .group_by(tb2.user_id)
)
```

above two queries and I want to apply FULL OUTER JOIN on them.

Answer (score 12):

Since 1.1. sqlalchemy now fully supports FULL OUTER JOINS. See here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join.params.full

So for your code you would want to do:

```
q1 = (db.session.query(
        tb1.user_id.label('u_id'),
        func.count(tb1.id).label('tb1_c')
    )
    .group_by(tb1.user_id)
).cte('q1')

q2 = (db.session.query(
        tb2.user_id.label('u_id'),
        func.count(tb2.id).label('tb2_c')
    )
    .group_by(tb2.user_id)
).cte('q2')

result = db.session.query(
    func.coalesce(q1.u_id, q2.u_id).label('u_id'),
    q1.tb1_c,
    q2.tb2_c
).join(
    q2,
    q1.u_id == q2.u_id,
    full=True
)
```

Note that as with any FULL OUTER JOIN, `tb1_c` and `tb2_c` may be null so you might want to apply a coalesce on them.

Comment: For people who are thinking of using this, I am citing the comment by @kpup in the accepted answer:
"Beware though, the query that's constructed may not work if your sql engine doesn't support full outer joins (mysql, for example)"

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `sqlalchemy` does not support `FULL JOIN` out of the box, and for some good reasons. So any solution proposed will consist of two parts:

1. a work-around for *missing* functionality
2. `sqlalchemy` syntax to build a query for that *work-around*

Now, for the reasons to avoid the `FULL JOIN`, please read some old blog [Better Alternatives to a FULL OUTER JOIN](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/19/Full-Outer-Joins.aspx).
From this very blog I will take the idea of how to *avoid* `FULL JOIN` by adding `0` values to the missing columns and aggregating (`SUM`) on `UNION ALL` intead. SA code might look something like below:

```
q1 = (session.query(
        tb1.user_id.label('u_id'),
        func.count(tb1.id).label('tb1_c'),
        literal(0).label('tb2_c'), # @NOTE: added 0
      ).group_by(tb1.user_id))
q2 = (session.query(
        tb2.user_id.label('u_id'),
        literal(0).label('tb1_c'), # @NOTE: added 0
        func.count(tb2.id).label('tb2_c')
      ).group_by(tb2.user_id))

qt = union_all(q1, q2).alias("united")
qr = select([qt.c.u_id, func.sum(qt.c.tb1_c), func.sum(qt.c.tb2_c)]).group_by(qt.c.u_id)
```

---

Having composed the query above, I actually might consider other options:

- simply execute those two queries separately and aggregate the results already in Python itself (for not so large results sets)
- given that it looks like some kind of reporting functionality rather than business model workflow, create a `SQL` query and execute it directly via `engine`. (only if it really is much better performing though)

Comment: sqlalchemy actually does support full outer joins as of version 1.1.  Beware though, the query that's constructed may not work if your sql engine doesn't support full outer joins (mysql, for example) http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join.params.full