# Sql Full outer join query does not work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have sql query where I am trying to do an full outer join, which works fine in SQL but does not work in Alchemy.

```
Select

Table1.field1 as Table1Field1, Table1.field2 as Table1Field2, 
Table2.field1 as Table2Field1, Table2.field2 as Table2Field2, 
Table3.field1 as Table3Field1, Table3.field2 as Table3Field2, 
Table4.field1 as Table4Field1, Table4.field2 as Table4Field2, 
Table5.field1 as Table5Field1, Table5.field2 as Table5Field2, 
Table7.field1 as Table7Field1, Table7.field2 as Table7Field2 


From Table1

full outer JOIN Table2 ON Table2.T1_id = Table1.id 
full outer JOIN Table3 ON Table3.T1_id = Table1.id 
full outer JOIN Table5 ON Table5.T1_id = Table1.id 
full outer JOIN Table4 ON Table4.id = Table5.T4_id
full outer JOIN Table7 ON Table7.id = Table5.T7_id;
```

T1_id is the foreign key in all the tables of the Table1.id

But The query I tried below I keep getting

```
    Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as 
providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

The query I tried

```
session.query(Table1).join(Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table7).
filter(Table2.T1_id = Table1.id, Table3.T1_id = Table1.id, Table4.T1_id =Table1.id, Table4.T5_id= Table5.id, Table4.T7_id = Table7.id).all()
```

I want the sqlAlchemy version where I can get the full outer join as given in the sql query.

```
More detailed error


 "help resolve the ambiguity." % (right,)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <class 'model.Table4'>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

Comment: Remove a comma in the end of select list

Comment: @Serg done, sorry missed that

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with just two tables?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361017/sqlalchemy-full-outer-join#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=First%20of%20all%2C%20sqlalchemy%20does,and%20for%20some%20good%20reasons.&text=sqlalchemy%20syntax%20to%20build%20a%20query%20for%20that%20work-around

Comment: The answer cited in the previous comment is very old, so note the [follow-up comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361017/sqlalchemy-full-outer-join#comment71077523_20387201) too.

Comment: @Gord Thompson it works fine with 2 tables, but the problem i think is from Table4.T1_id & Table7.T1_id being compared with Table5.id

Comment: i have given an updated in detail error

Answer (score 0):

```
session.query(Table1).join(Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table7).
filter(Table2.id = Table1.id, Table3.id = Table1.id, Table4.id = Table5.id, Table7.id = Table5.id).all()
```

I above query Table1, Table2 and Table3 are connected and Table4, Table5 Table7 are connected but there is no connection between these two sets of tables.

This is a good read:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join.params.full

Please establish a connection between all the tables then add `full=true`

```
    session.query(Table1).join(Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table7).
        filter(Table2.id = Table1.id, Table3.id = Table1.id, 
Table4.T1.id = Table1.id, Table4.id = Table5.id, Table7.id = Table5.id,full=true).all()
```

Comment: Is there a relationship exists between any of table1,table2 or table3 and table4,table5 or table7?

Comment: yes, table5,7 has with table 4, table 2,3,4 has with table1

Comment: Table4.id=Table1.id?

Comment: it is Table4.T1.id = Table1.id

Comment: please try my revise answer though I am not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230413/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-penta).